# Is there any possibilities to set Fedex for particular products?

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, fedex

Is there any possibilities to set Fedex for particular products.
If we enabled Fedex it comes for all products We need only specified products.

Comment: By default Magento has no options for this, we need to do some code changes like logic changes in core part.